# Refer to line below search text in text file

Tags: excel, vba

I have data such as the following in a text file:

```
Member A
      Diameter      60 in
      Thickness     1  in
      Yield Stress  50 ksi

Brace B
      Diameter      54 in
      Thickness     1  in
      Yield Stress  50 ksi
```

I need to extract numerical diameter (or thickness, or yield stress) when a string of text "Member A" is found within a long text file.  Data is always in same order.

I can extract data that is on the same line as the text I'm searching for using "Trim" / "Mid".  I do not know how to refer to "the line below" the text I'm searching for.

My code:

```
Sub jtdtlextract()
    Dim str, str1, strOutPut, strBrcAngle, strComnJt, strChrdDia As String
    Dim FileToOpen, FileConverted, strRun, lngReturn, fs, f, s, ff

    FileToOpen = Application.GetOpenFilename("All Files (*.*), *.*")
    If FileToOpen <> False Then
        MsgBox FileToOpen, 0, "Open File"
    End If

    Set fs = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    Set f = fs.GetFile(FileToOpen)

    FileConverted = UCase(f.ParentFolder.Path) & "\jt_dtls_extracted.txt"

    Open FileToOpen For Input Access Read Shared As #1
    Open FileConverted For Output Access Write Shared As #2

    Do Until EOF(1)
        Line Input #1, str
        str1 = LTrim(str)
        If Left(str1, 31) = "Detailed Review Report of Joint" Then
             strComnJt = Trim(Mid(str1, 35, 4))
             strOutPut = "Common_Jt" & Space(1) & strComnJt
             Print #2, strOutPut
        End If
                'I have a lot more information to extract from the text file
                'I was hoping to use a method similar to above since it's
                'fairly simple and I have no coding experience, the code
                'above only works when the information needed is on the
                'same line as the information searched for. Was written
                'by someone else.
    Loop
    Close #1
    Close #2

    strRun = "Notepad.exe " & FileConverted
    lngReturn = Shell(strRun)

End Sub
```

Comment: It would help to show your existing code.

Comment: +1 tim. Also@rayray: vba or vbscript?

Comment: Just answered a similar question here... http://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?704421-Search-text-file-for-keywords-and-input-information-into-excel-columns

Comment: @TimWilliams & SiddharthRout I've posted my code if that is useful

question is for vba

Comment: I think it would involve changing quite a bit, but a regular expression to extract `60` from your example (for Member A) would be `Member A[\r]\n\s+Diameter\s+([0-9]+)`

Answer (score 0):

You'll need some state-management code to keep track of where you are in the file.

If the file is not too big you don't need full-streaming and can use full-**buffering** in an array.

Then you can naturally scan this array using simple indexing :

```
name = lines(i)
diameter = parseDiameter(lines(i+1))
thickness = parseThickness(lines(i+2))
yieldStress = parseYieldStress(lines(i+3))
i = i + 5
```

Comment: Thanks for the response Serious, I might be able to try something like that

Answer (score 0):

```
 Do Until EOF(1)
    Line Input #1, str
    str1 = LTrim(str)
    If Left(str1, 31) = "Detailed Review Report of Joint" Then
            strComnJt = Trim(Mid(str1, 35, 4))
            strOutPut = "Common_Jt" & Space(1) & strComnJt
            Print #2, strOutPut

            Line Input #1, strDiscardThisLine
            Line Input #1, str3rdLine
            strOutPut = Trim(Mid(str3rdLine,35,4))
            Print #2, strOutPut

    End If
```